# Can I get a Schengen (tourist) visa with an existing type-D visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

While the D visa is not yet expired.

New visa will be issued from a different country (assuming it is possible)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you think a Schengen visa would be useful to you if you hold a valid type D visa?  Is it because the trip you're planning will take place after the type D visa expires or for some other reason?

Comment: "the trip you're planning will take place after the type D visa expires" yep

Comment: On the day of Schengen visa application, I will have a residence permit application in process from the country that issued my D visa. But by the time I want to enter EU, D visa will not be valid. That's why I'll need a new visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory it ought to be possible, generally speaking, to obtain a C visa while you have a D visa, in order to enable a trip after the expiration of the D visa.  In practice, the requirement to apply for a C visa from your place of residence makes this difficult.  In your case, however, there is another more significant problem.  You write:

> On the day of Schengen visa application, I will have a residence permit application in process from the country that issued my D visa. But by the time I want to enter EU, D visa will not be valid. That's why I'll need a new visa.

You won't qualify for a type C visa because one of the requirements is to demonstrate your intention to leave the Schengen area, while you have no such intention.

To reenter the Schengen area with a pending residence permit application you should probably get another type D visa from the country where you are living.  This may or may not be possible.  Unfortunately, being stuck in a country during the processing of a residence permit application is a common problem that often has no good solution.

The specific solution (or unavailability of a solution) depends on your country of residence, since these matters are governed by national law.  If you want some help with this, consider posting a question on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Shouldn't the country offer some "bridge visa", at least the Czech Republic does. https://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/third-country-nationals-long-term-residence.aspx?q=Y2hudW09MTU%3D

Comment: Oh yes being stuck is the problem I am trying to avoid... So there's really no solution? Then I guess I must return before visa expiration

Comment: @NelsonGon nah this one doesn't issue that

Comment: What country is it?

Comment: @NelsonGon Is there a PM function on this site?

Comment: @oooooo "so there's really no solution?": It's impossible to say whether a solution exists without knowing which country you're asking about.  In many countries it will also depend on the type of residence application (skilled worker, family reunion, student, other; the rules may vary from one type to another).  Some countries don't issue bridging visas because they consider the application abandoned if you leave.  Without more information it's impossible to be more helpful.

Comment: Fair enough. "Some countries don't issue bridging visas because they consider the application abandoned if you leave." How can I learn if a particular country is one of them?

Comment: @oooooo the most straightforward way is to ask the office that is processing your residence permit application whether it's possible for you to leave the country and return without affecting the application, and, if so, how to obtain a document allowing your return.

Comment: (+1) One way to approach this would be to ask a question detailing your actual problem (where you live, your exact status, and how long you want to be away) on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ without making too many assumptions on what a solution might look like (as you seem to have done in this question).